# Unable to install 'ijavascript'

Tags: node.js, npm, anaconda, jupyter, ijavascript

Here is the link for complete error logs - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rm52sXPsCUskP2EHX-6pBPRoZqaH_ypY/view?usp=sharing

Apparently error is due to some **zeromq module** starting with

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Parth\anaconda3\envs\jsenv\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\zeromq
npm ERR! command failed
```

I have tried -
Downgrading the python version ,upgrading npm ,
Reinstalling in new environment , adding path to environment variables.